# Meaning of I have not to go there

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, subject-verb-agreement

Let's have a look at these sentences:

1.**I have to not go there**.

2.**I don't have to go there**.

3.**I have not to go there**.

What are the meanings of these sentences.

I think, the first one means that it is forbidden for me to go there.

The second one means that there's no compulsion on me to go there. If I want to go there I can and if I don't want to I can too.

And what does the third one mean? Is it same as first one or the second one?

Please let me know if all the meanings derived from these sentences are correct or not.

Comment: The first is unnatural. It's better written: "*I must not go there.*" The second you're right about. The third is bad grammar.

Comment: #2 is the only natural one.  It's hard to imagine any native speaker saying #1 or #3.

Comment: @stangdon - [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+haven%27t+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20have%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that #3 was sometimes used in the past, meaning the same as _I don't have to_. For instance, the singer Kathleen Ferrier wrote in 1950 "That's something I haven't to worry about."

Comment: @KateBunting so, accepting sahil-laskar's interpretations, you would say that #3 means the same as #2?

Comment: @djs - That's what I said. Ferrier meant that she did not need to worry about the issue.

Comment: @KateBunting  Good observation.  I also think the usage in #3 might be traditionally a little more UK than US; [Ngrams seems to bear that out.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28I+haven%27t+to%3Aeng_gb_2019%29%2F%28I+haven%27t+to%3Aeng_us_2019%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28I%20have%20not%20to%3Aeng_gb_2019%29%20/%20%28I%20have%20not%20to%3Aeng_us_2019%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @KateBunting we use 'must not' to show prohibition ,in other words for negative obligation right? Now if want to show prohibition using 'have to' ,what will be the way to use it ? I think that would be 'have to + not something ' . I'm getting stuck here. Please clarify.

Comment: If you must use _have to_, you would need to say _You have to stop doing X, You have to avoid doing X_ or similar. You can't _have to not_ do something.

Comment: @KateBunting I've just posted a question related to it. Here I can't properly say what I want to . Please have a look to the question I've just posted.