# Why does "You have not to do it" mean "You don't have to do it"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

**I'm requesting you to do it** .

**I'm requesting you not to do it**.

Both make sense. The second one doesn't mean that "I'm not requesting you to it" rather it talks about prohibition.
But,

**You have to do it**.

**You have not to do it**.

Why does this sentence mean " You don't have to do it"? Rather it should mean that " You're forbidden to do it".

I'm not a native English speaker. Maybe that's why I'm missing something. Please clarify with proper explanations.

Comment: "You have not to do it" does not seem correct to me at all.

Answer (score 1):

As was discussed earlier [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/320665/meaning-of-i-have-not-to-go-there), **You haven't to do it** is not very idiomatic nowadays, but *when it was in more common use, mainly in British English* it had the sense 'You don't have to do it."

You just have to accept that, in English usage, **have to** always means that something is required or necessary. The negative version is **must not**, unless you use it with a negative verb such as **have to stop, have to avoid** and so on.

Comment: I was just comparing later ones with the previous ones. Now I got it.